# git push --force will push wrong branch

Tags: git

I have a main branch "dev", and I checked out a branch "A" based on dev. Here are the steps I took:

1. Do modification on A, commit, then push and merge to dev.
2. A has been deleted on server.
3. Still made some changes on local A.
4. I tried to push local A to server. i.e. on branch A, do `git push --force`
5. I found the dev on server was force updated by my local dev.

My question is, Why dev was updated by my local dev, if I did `git push --force` on local A branch?

```bash
# BSDC-587_For_EMC_test has been merged to dev on server, and deleted on server
# Made some modifications and commit 
$ git status

On branch BSDC-587_For_EMC_test
Your branch is ahead of 'dummy-ondemand/dev' by 5 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   ../rtos/ssp/app/svc/config/AmbaCamCtrl.c
    modified:   ../rtos/ssp/app/svc/main/AmbaOpModeCtrlTask.c

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    pkg/network_turnkey/source/usr/local/share/script/emc_download.sh
    ../rtos/mcu_image/bsd_mcu.bin

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ git add ../rtos/ssp/app/svc/config/AmbaCamCtrl.c
$ git add ../rtos/ssp/app/svc/main/AmbaOpModeCtrlTask.c
$ git branch

* BSDC-587_For_EMC_test
  dev

$ git commit -m "BSDC-578 add network checking and downloading"

[BSDC-587_For_EMC_test 85f42e7] BSDC-578 add network checking and downloading
 2 files changed, 33 insertions(+), 4 deletions(-)

// Try to push local branch to server, but it seems like git try to push dev branch

$ git push

To ssh://git@bitbucket.org/dummy-ondemand/tsdk-code.git
 ! [rejected]        dev -> dev (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@bitbucket.org/dummy-ondemand/tsdk-code.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

$ cd ..
$ git pull

remote: Counting objects: 148, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (148/148), done.
remote: Total 148 (delta 132), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (148/148), 157.20 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (132/132), completed with 53 local objects.
From ssh://bitbucket.org/dummy-ondemand/tsdk-code
   b2de179..9a75859  dev        -> dummy-ondemand/dev
 * [new branch]      BSDC-592_store_IMSI_to_flash_at_boot -> dummy-ondemand/BSDC-592_store_IMSI_to_flash_at_boot
 + 07459ca...531ec19 BSDC_faster_time_to_first_picture -> dummy-ondemand/BSDC_faster_time_to_first_picture  (forced update)
Auto-merging rtos/ssp/app/svc/main/AmbaOpModeCtrlTask.c
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in rtos/ssp/app/svc/main/AmbaOpModeCtrlTask.c
Recorded preimage for 'rtos/ssp/app/svc/main/AmbaOpModeCtrlTask.c'
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

$ git status

On branch BSDC-587_For_EMC_test
Your branch and 'dummy-ondemand/dev' have diverged,
and have 6 and 2 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")

Changes to be committed:

    modified:   rtos/bsp/trailcam/bsp.c
    modified:   rtos/bsp/trailcam/ringbuffer.c
    modified:   rtos/bsp/trailcam/ringbuffer.h
    modified:   rtos/ssp/app/svc/AmbaUserSysCtrl.c

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

    both modified:   rtos/ssp/app/svc/main/AmbaOpModeCtrlTask.c

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    ambalink_sdk_4_9/pkg/network_turnkey/source/usr/local/share/script/emc_download.sh
    rtos/mcu_image/bsd_mcu.bin

$ vi rtos/ssp/app/svc/main/AmbaOpModeCtrlTask.c
$ git add rtos/ssp/app/svc/main/AmbaOpModeCtrlTask.c
$ git commit 

Recorded resolution for 'rtos/ssp/app/svc/main/AmbaOpModeCtrlTask.c'.
[BSDC-587_For_EMC_test a46f1b9] Merge branch 'dev' of ssh://bitbucket.org/dummy-ondemand/tsdk-code into BSDC-587_For_EMC_test
ldy2534@ubuntu:~/Project/project_mcu/context/tekdev/tsdk-code$ git status
On branch BSDC-587_For_EMC_test
Your branch is ahead of 'dummy-ondemand/dev' by 7 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    ambalink_sdk_4_9/pkg/network_turnkey/source/usr/local/share/script/emc_download.sh
    rtos/mcu_image/bsd_mcu.bin

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

$ git branch

* BSDC-587_For_EMC_test
  dev
ldy2534@ubuntu:~/Project/project_mcu/context/tekdev/tsdk-code$ git rebase dev
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: BSDC-587 EMC test wifi working version
Applying: BSDC-587 improve network connection
Applying: BSDC-587 tidy up code
Applying: BSDC-578 add more comments
Applying: BSDC-587 modifications according to review
Applying: Merged in BSDC-510_fix_x_uart_lost_messages (pull request #178)
Applying: Merged in BSDC-587_For_EMC_test (pull request #177)
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M   ambalink_sdk_4_9/pkg/bsd_app/tekipc_projectlink.cpp
M   ambalink_sdk_4_9/pkg/bsd_app/tekipc_projectlink.h
M   ambalink_sdk_4_9/pkg/bsd_app/xsmtp.cpp
M   ambalink_sdk_4_9/pkg/bsd_app/xsmtp.h
M   rtos/bsp/trailcam/devices.h
M   rtos/ssp/app/svc/bsd_app/tekipc_bsd.cpp
M   rtos/ssp/app/svc/bsd_app/tekipc_bsd.h
M   rtos/ssp/app/svc/config/AmbaCamCtrl.c
M   rtos/ssp/app/svc/format/AmbaMovMuxer.c
M   rtos/ssp/app/svc/main/AmbaOpModeCtrlTask.c
M   rtos/ssp/app/svc/main/AmbaPostProc.c
M   rtos/ssp/app/svc/main/AmbaRecTask.c
M   rtos/ssp/app/svc/main/DemoTask.c
M   rtos/ssp/app/svc/main/inc/AmbaPostProc.h
M   rtos/ssp/app/svc/main/inc/AmbaSVC.h
.git/rebase-apply/patch:86: trailing whitespace.
        return false; 
.git/rebase-apply/patch:665: trailing whitespace.
    
.git/rebase-apply/patch:588: new blank line at EOF.
+
.git/rebase-apply/patch:671: new blank line at EOF.
+
warning: 4 lines add whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
No changes -- Patch already applied.
Applying: BSDC-578 add network checking and downloading

$ tig
$ git status

On branch BSDC-587_For_EMC_test
Your branch and 'dummy-ondemand/dev' have diverged,
and have 7 and 2 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    ambalink_sdk_4_9/pkg/network_turnkey/source/usr/local/share/script/emc_download.sh
    rtos/mcu_image/bsd_mcu.bin

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

$ git add ambalink_sdk_4_9/pkg/network_turnkey/source/usr/local/share/script/emc_download.sh
$ git commit -m "BSDC-578 add emc_download script"

[BSDC-587_For_EMC_test a0983d0] BSDC-578 add emc_download script
 1 file changed, 5 insertions(+)
 create mode 100755 ambalink_sdk_4_9/pkg/network_turnkey/source/usr/local/share/script/emc_download.sh

$ git push 

To ssh://git@bitbucket.org/dummy-ondemand/tsdk-code.git
 ! [rejected]        dev -> dev (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@bitbucket.org/dummy-ondemand/tsdk-code.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

$ git push --force

Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: 
remote: Create pull request for dev:
remote:   https://bitbucket.org/dummy-ondemand/tsdk-code/pull-requests/new?source=dev&t=1
remote: 
To ssh://git@bitbucket.org/dummy-ondemand/tsdk-code.git
 + 9a75859...b2de179 dev -> dev (forced update)

$ git branch

* BSDC-587_For_EMC_test
  dev
```

Comment: Ok... I'm not reading that entire transcript, and I doubt anyone else is either, so I suggest you come up with minimal steps to reproduce the problem.  I did read far enough to see that the very first push in the transcript appears to try pushing `dev` while you're on a branch, which means you should look at the various configuration values that affect how `push` behaves.  See the `git push` docs for information about those config variables.

Comment: What's your git version? (`git --version`) On older versions, the default `push.default` [option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pushdefault) was set to `matching` so when you did `git push` without giving explicitly the refs you want to push, each branch would be pushed to its remote counterpart. Might not be that. Just to mention it.

Comment: If you're not fully confident with git, please use `git push <remote> <branch>` and `git pull <remote> <branch>`, so you always know WHICH branch your pulling/pushing.

Comment: And check `git branch -vv` for upstreams

Answer (score 0):

as you can see there is an asterisk next to the BSDC-587_For_EMC_test branch.
when you preformed git pull it also pulled the dev branch from the server.
if you will do:

```
$ git checkout dev
```

and go back to your code, i presume you will find out it wasn't updated at all from your local branch.

Answer (score 0):

In the very first `git status`, it displays:

```
On branch BSDC-587_For_EMC_test
Your branch is ahead of 'dummy-ondemand/dev' by 5 commits.
```

Right away something is wrong. Your local branch has the `dummy-ondemand/dev` set as its upstream branch. This means that (by default) any `git push` command (forced or otherwise) will try to update `dummy-ondemand/dev`.

Clearly, this is not what you intend to happen. Without knowing how you created this branch and the full history of what you did, it is impossible to say how you got into this state.

**To fix the current issue**

1. `git checkout BSDC-587_For_EMC_test` - Switch to the correct branch
2. `git branch --unset-upstream` - Remove the current upstream association to `dev`
3. `git push -u dummy-ondemand BSDC-587_For_EMC_test` - Create branch `BSDC-587_For_EMC_test` on the remote `dummy-ondemand` AND set the local upstream to it

Now `git push` will not cause changes to `dummy-ondemand/dev`.